# Netty UDP Multicast Not Supported With Epoll. Why?

Tags: udp, netty, multicast, epoll

In the class [EpollDatagramChannelConfig](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollDatagramChannelConfig.html), there are 4 methods that look like this:

```
@Override
public EpollDatagramChannelConfig setTimeToLive(int ttl) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Multicast not supported");
}
```

These are:

- [setLoopbackModeDisabled](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollDatagramChannelConfig.html#309)
- [setTimeToLive](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollDatagramChannelConfig.html#319)
- [setInterface](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollDatagramChannelConfig.html#329)
- [setNetworkInterface](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/epoll/EpollDatagramChannelConfig.html#339)

Is support disabled due to an issue in Netty, or does Epoll simply not support UDP multicast ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its disabled because no-one did implement it yet. That said contributions are welcome.